# Sync laravel mix static assets with shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

after uploading laravel project to server, I want to deploy new changes to server like javascript files changes.
I use command

```
npm run watch
```

to mix all styles and scripts.

unfortunately, Changes do not apply to the website

Comment: You should not do this, you should only push your resources assets and `npm run prod` on the server once in a while

Comment: npm not installed on the server, how can i run this command on the server?

Comment: Install nodejs and run npm

Comment: I use shared hosting. how can i install nodejs? They do not have access to such a thing at all.

Comment: If you're using shared hosting, then do not say "'server" because we assume root privileges to a VPS

Comment: So what's your suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Use GitHub hooks to auto-deploy pushed committed changes